# Rendering templates using backbone and Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, express, underscore.js

I'm currently working on web development side project. I have been trying to figure out all the pieces for the last couple of months and have made good progress.

I'm using bootstrap and Backbone on the front end and this is what I have been focusing on lately. This part works well with all the Backbone views being rendered fine.

For the backend I will use Nodejs along with express. I have started looking into it this past week. Currently, I'm trying to serve requests sent to the server with through express.

How can I handle the request and send back a Backbone view that already has a defined HTML page and everything.

I came across Jade which is used with express a lot but I can't get it to work with my backbone views. Also, how does underscore come into the picture. Do I have to choose between underscore and Jade?

I will of course further down the line have data pulled from a database and sent to the backbone views.

Thank you for any input.

Answer (score 1):

Underscore (_.template method) and Jade both can, from a template file, render html code which will be sent by express to the client. Since underscore is not express friendly my guess is that you are confusing the client libraries (Used by backbone on the browser) and the server libraries user by nodeJS to answer request calls, if you are rendering templates using underscore with backbone that is done client side and has nothing to do with express.

This article should help you set everything up: http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/10/nodecellar-sample-application-with-backbone-js-twitter-bootstrap-node-js-express-and-mongodb/ and it has source code for you to look at.

Since my guess is you want something functional fast, I would suggest something like sails.js which can save you a lot of time configuring express and making it work. Plus sails.js its built on top of express. https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will look into sails later tonight. The wine cellar app you mentioned is actually what I started with in the beginning and built on it. So I also have HTML/views that have underscore templates. But as mentioned on that page, these are all rendered by the client. Now I'm not sure whether this is I should be continue with. I was able to convert an HTML view into a Jade view but I'm not sure if it's worth redoing all that on the server.

Comment: Unless you want your server side code to alter the index.html there is not need to convert anything to a jade template. Backbone should load from the index.html file and express should answer every request for a file inside the public folder.

Comment: How would you go about doing that? My index page is just header and footer. The content is filled by as needed, it also has all dependencies to kick off the app. It's a single page app. How can express load any HTML file in the public folder? I can't get it working without somehow loading index before that since it initializes all rest of js files. Thank you again for your answer. Highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. My point was that you didn't need to convert anything to Jade, since jade is used server side and just serving the static index.html will kick off your app. Note: Sorry for the late answer I just saw this! :$

Comment: Thank you again for your comment. My setup is exactly as you mentioned. I thought I would need to somehow serve every html file depending on the requested URL. However, it seems that by just serving the index.html file, any path would work (e.g. /about or /profile). Is this expected/reasonable behavior? Thanks again.